# Локализация внутри запроса

Tags: oracle, sql

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно при помощи одного SQL-запроса получить дату с названием месяца на конкретном языке?
Следующая команда:

```
Select STNAME,
to_char(BIRTHDAY,'DAY MONTH DD, YYYY', ‘nls_date_language=russian’) As Birthday
From user19.Student
Where STNAME like '%O_';
```

пытается вывести названия месяцев на русском, но возникает проблема с кодировкой (в результате крокозябры). Как одной командой вывести дату на конкретном языке?
Спасибо

Comment: сервер назовите. Оракул я так думаю

Comment: Да, сервер оракловый.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать ф-цию [CONVERT()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions034.htm). 
Но для этого надо знать(определить) исходную и требуемую кодировки.